# What is a basic model for making a database with users and groups?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to find the best way for a basic security system for a website.  I know I want users and groups.

I thought I'd have:

```
user_table
user_id
user_name
...

group_type
group_id
group_name
parent_id
...

group_table
id
user_id
group_id
```

First one is the user, second one is the group, and the third one is the intermediary table that connects the two.  One user has many groups.

Does this sound ok?

Comment: Other than the names.  Your `GROUP_TYPE` table should be named `GROUP` or something similar, and your `GROUP_TABLE` should reference both Users and Groups, as that's what it's linking.

Comment: @adam doesn't group_table do that with user_id and group_id?

Comment: @AdamMusch It should not be named GROUP, as that is a reserved word. Tables and columns should never be named after reserved words

Comment: @Phil agreed.  You may as well name a table `SELECT` and a field `FROM` so you can have a query like `SELECT [FROM] FROM [SELECT]`

Comment: Try calling the basic entities something like 'app_user' and 'app_role'

Comment: @Phil - in my defense, I did say `GROUP` or something similar.  You are correct about not using reserved words, however.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The traditional way to model this is using a pattern called **Role-Based Security**.

The idea is not just to have groups of users, but also groups of permissions. Here is how the pattern looks:

[image: Role Based Security ERD]

*Note that you want to avoid reserved words for table names, so don't name your tables exactly as shown in the diagram.*

The way it works is that your groups or *Roles* have not only a list of users assigned to them but also a list of permissions assigned to them.  This allows you to table-drive both who can do what, but also what it is they can do, if you follow me.

Comment: But what if my user has some role like manager or whatever and for some reason the same user needs one particular permission as well (which is not in that role, nor is in any other role alone)?

Comment: @levi - If that happens then one way to handle it is to make a special role like _"Bob's Special Permissions"_, which is a bit of a kludge, but it solves the problem as long as you don't have too many exceptions like this.  It is possible that what you think is an individual exception may actually be a subtle new role that you haven't considered.  What happens when Bob quits?  Does Bob's replacement also need that exceptional permission?  If so then you actually have a role with one member, not an exception.

Comment: @levi - Another possibility is that you really need to have a mixture of individual and role rights.  In that case, your `ROLE` table can be subtyped into _Individual_ and _Group_ types, where the group type has zero to many members and the individual type has exactly one member.  How you enforce these cardinality rules is up to you.  It could be done declaratively in your database schema, in which case you need to change the pictured schema slightly.  Or you might use application logic, in which case your schema still looks like what I've pictured above.